# In ASP.NET user control, i want to expose a method to client side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an User Control Which is having a lot of lot methods. 
I want to expose a method to client. So that i can call the method of the control in javascript and get the result.

For Example:
A method called, GetData(), which will get the data from the server. Currently i am calling this method only on code behind. It will return the data. Now i want to call the same method in client side.

Is it possible?

Comment: you need to wrap the method in some kind of web service. However   you should move it to it's own class, and call the method in the new class in your user control and your web service.

Comment: You might want to rethink your architecture. Why is a user control exposing data to a client? This likely leads to a bad design where you don't have clear Separation of Concerns. Instead, you should look into creating an API based on Microsoft's [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) and expose the data through that.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of approaches, which will vary on your technology.  If your project is using:

- **Web-Forms:**

Example:

```
<div>
     <span><%= GetData(Eval("Data Column").ToString()) %></span>
</div>
```

That would be your front end, you notice how your exposing the method.

```
protected string GetData(string content)
{
     // Do Something.
}
```

That is the code behind, which is your method.  It must be `protected` or `public` it can not be `private`.

- **Web-Method:** This is viable, but as mentioned above it isn't supported anymore. So I won't provide an example, though they exist.
- **Model View Controller:**

Example:

```
<div>
     <span>@{ ClassName.GetData() }</span>
</div>
```

That is the front end, as you notice you use Razor to expose the method from behind. That will help you call a method from the `Controller`.

Those are a couple of approaches, hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use webmethods:

Have a look at:
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: WebMethods are no longer supported by Microsoft. [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) is what you should be using (and recommending).

Comment: WebMethods must be static, So other than static things, we cannot access anything in the WebMethod(static) method. So How i can call the Instance method of the User Control inside a WebMethod.